# Defining commands of commands

Tags: macros, sectioning, chapters

If you want to include an image in your chapter title, what follows may be an option:

```
\newcommand{\thechapterimage}{}
\newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{\renewcommand{\thechapterimage}{#1}}
\def\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\def\@makechapterhead#1{%
{\centering \normalfont\sffamily
\ifnum \c@secnumdepth >\m@ne
\if@mainmatter
\vspace*{-3.9cm}\hspace*{-3.1cm}% to position the figure
\includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\thechapterimage}\par
\rput[lb](0,2){\sffamily\bfseries\thechapter}}\par
\vspace*{30\p@}%
}
```

Then, in the main document, you would call the name of a figure just before the chapter command:

```
\chapterimage{image.eps}
\chapter{Title}
```

What is the exact role of the first two commands `\thechapterimage` and `\chapterimage` above?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you have prior programming experience, it may help to think of it this way (although that’s not actually what’s happening):

`\thechapterimage` is a variable (which stores the image path), and to assign a new value to this variable, you need to write `\renewcommand\thechapterimage{some value}`.

Now, this is obviously very cumbersome when done repeatedly so we define a shortcut for this “assignment.” The shortcut corresponds to a method (more precisely, a setter method): it gets one parameter and *sets* the value:

```
\newcommand\chapterimage[1]{\renewcommand\thechapterimage{#1}}
```

Clearly, this “setter” is executing the same assignment as above. Strictly speaking, you don’t need the `\chapterimage` macro but it makes the code simpler and clearer.

Comment: my question to Will was: in what sense \thechapterimage is different from \chapterimage. \thechapterimage is a varaible that can store a path, and then \chapterimage is what? what's inside?

Comment: why cannot we store a path in \chapterimage?

Comment: @pluton: Actually, I had intended to describe precisely that. Well, try again: `\chapterimage` is not a variable, it’s a method. The code in your comment to Will’s post cannot work for obvious reasons: you declare `\chapterimage` to take one argument – but in your usage later you use it without specifying arguments. `\chapterimage` doesn’t “store” anything, as it were. It is just a shortcut for setting the variable.

Comment: \chapterimage is a method, ok, but could it be possible to achieve the same result by using \chapterimage only (no call to \thechapterimage or so)? Thanks

Comment: If you insist ... \newcommand\chapterimage[1]{\def\chapterimage{#1}} ... But it only works once. You could reset it after every call to \chapter, but I don't see the advantage of doing it this way.

Comment: @pluton: Where do you store the image path? You need to store it *somewhere*, don’t you?

Comment: @Konrad: I know but I am trying to understand the difference between \something and \thesomething

Comment: @pluton: **there is none** – The names are completely arbitrary (though convention). If it weren’t convention, clearer names might be `\thevalueoffoo` and `\setfoo`, respectively. But again, these are just names for the user, they don’t impart any semantics.

Answer (score 5):

You probably mean "why not using directly `\renewcommand\thechapterimage{image}` in the document instead of the detour with `\chapterimage`". That is possible too, but it is

1. longer and
2. means that a user has to use `\renewcommand` regularly. Package writer write in such cases often a wrapper command which hides the `\def`/`\renewcommand` from the user. Other examples for such wrapper commands are `\title` and `\author`.

Answer (score 2):

`\chapterimage` (re)defines `\thechapterimage` which is used inside `\chapter`.

Comment: and why not \newcommand{\chapterimage}[1]{#1} and then 
includegraphics[width=\paperwidth]{\chapterimage} ?

Comment: That doesn't make sense. Try it and see.

Comment: yes, this is silly (see Konrad's comment)